# How to take dynamic input from flask and pass it to other function?

Tags: python, api, flask

How can I take input from url in flask from the parameter?

```
@app.route('/<id>')
def give_id(id):
    
    return id
```

I need to take the above Id from input and pass it to other function without again needing to write `"id"`

```
def some_function():
    variable1 = vid_stream.get_hls_url(give_id("I need to again pass that Id here"))
```

How can I directly use the id from `give_id(id)` function and feed it into `vid_stream.get_hls_url` function?

Posting complete demo code, In case someone needs to run locally.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<id>')
def give_id(id):
        
   return id

def some_function():
   variable1 = vid_stream.get_hls_url(give_id("I need to again pass that Id here"))
   print(variable1)
some_function()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)
```

Comment: Consider using a flask wrapper like flask-restful. This will make a lot of things like this more easy. See an example here https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#full-example. You can have class based views, so you can keep the state available for anytime you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. `id` is reserved keyword so i have renamed it you can call the function by passing the value. You can call `some_function` from you `give_id` view directly.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

def some_function(p_id):
   variable1 = vid_stream.get_hls_url(give_id("I need to again pass that Id here"))
   print(variable1)
   return variable1

@app.route('/<id>')
def give_id(p_id):
   output = some_function(p_id) 
   return p_id



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)
```